# AWS API Gateway: Can't use CORS and API Key authentication together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm using AWS SAM to create a few Lambda functions that get triggered by API-Gateway events.

In general, it's working, but I need to add two features: CORS, and API key authentication.

I've been able to set it so that an API Key is required to call the API.

Here is the `Globals` section of my `template.yaml`:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    Auth:
      ApiKeyRequired: true
```

This works perfectly.

I've also been able to set it so that it supports CORS.

Here is the `Resources/Api` section my my `template.yaml`:

```
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowCredentials: "'*'"
```

However, it only works if I do ***one or the other.***

In other words, if I do ***both***:

```
Globals:
  Api:
    Auth:
      ApiKeyRequired: true
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowCredentials: "'*'"
```

... it stops working.

Specifically, the sam CLI tool builds and deploys the sam app; however, if I call the API in a browser, the requests fail:

[image]

Here is the specific error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://75hkwcgiy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/plans/35580' from origin 'http://[mydomain].com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://75hkwcgiy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/plans/35580 net::ERR_FAILED
```

Any insight on why this is the case, and how to fix it so I can support both CORS and API key authentication?

Comment: What is the error and status code?

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana The error is `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://75hkwcgiy.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/plans/35580' from origin 'http://[mydomain].com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `AllowCredentials` be `true`?

Comment: You might be right. However, if I set `AllowCredentials: true`, then I get an error: `Unable to add Cors configuration because 'AllowCredentials' can not be true when 'AllowOrigin' is "'*'" or not set`.

Comment: @mattstuehler you can't use wildchar `*` in `AllowOrigin`, when `AllowCredentials: true`. You need to set origins explicitly instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it fails with ApiKeyRequired true and CORS turned on is that the ApiKeyRequired is adding the api key required attribute to all the options calls, which causes the preflight to fail as it's not standard to have authentication details in an options call.

If you're trying to define all the integrations in a swagger/openapi template, I don't have the solution to get around this.

You can get around this by defining the integrations using events in the lambda and specifying which methods should have api key enabled, then remove the ApiKeyRequired from the gateway.

On your lambda have

```
Events:
    HttpGet:
      Type: Api 
      Properties:
        Path: "/jobs"
        Method: GET
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
        Auth:
          ApiKeyRequired: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention *"if I call the API in a browser"* it generates an error.

The error stems from a security mechanism that browsers implement called the **same-origin policy**. [See David Katz's Medium post.](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9)

Katz provides more detailed information on the error, its causes, and some solution options.  These include using a browser plugin or a proxy server (yours or someone else's).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm not sure about this. The API specification I'm using above should specifically enable that API to accept CORS requests.

Comment: I don't think your API configuration has anything to do with a browser's security behavior.